# How to open submenus in a dropdown to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below drop down menu when we hover over the items, the submenu opens to the right. But, I want that it opens to the left instead.

Here the code:

html:

```
<div id="mn-wrapper">

    <div class="mn-sidebar">
        <div class="mn-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
        <div class="mn-navblock">
            <ul class="mn-vnavigation">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu active">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">LARGE HOLDINGS</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu third-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu active"><a href="#">LHO</a>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu parent third-menu">
                    <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <a href="#">Contact Us
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right" style="display:none;"></span>
                </a>

<ul class="child">
<li style="padding:10px 0; color:white;"><font color = C8CBCC size = 2><b>Hotline:</b></font> 8828 5600</li>
<li style="padding:10px 0; color:white;"><font color = C8CBCC size = 2 ><b>Support Mailbox:</b></font> <font face = "Barclays Sans">Compliance Application 

Support L1</font></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
<a href="#">Application Overview
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right" style="display:none;"></span>
</a>

<ul class="child">
<li style="padding:10px 0; color:white;"><font color = C8CBCC size = 2><b>LHO </b></font></br></br><font size=2> Web Application to track large equity 

holdings and, where appropriate, report to regulators. It is owned by the Compliance Department.</font></li>
</ul>
</li>      
</ul>
</li>



         </ul>




</li>



 <li class="dropdown-submenu active">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">ORCHESTRIA</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu third-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu active"><a href="#">ORCHESTRIA</a>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu parent third-menu">
                    <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <a href="#">Contact Us
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right" style="display:none;"></span>
                </a>

<ul class="child">
<li style="padding:10px 0; color:white;"><font color = C8CBCC size = 2><b>Hotline:</b></font> 8828 5600</li>
<li style="padding:10px 0; color:white;"><font color = C8CBCC size = 2 ><b>Support Mailbox:</b></font> <font face = "Barclays Sans">Compliance Application 

Support L1</font></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
<a href="#">Application Overview
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right" style="display:none;"></span>
</a>

<ul class="child">
<li style="padding:10px 0; color:white;"><font color = C8CBCC size = 2><b>ORCHESTRIA</b></font> </br></br><font size=2> E-mail and instant messaging 

monitoring and intelligent review using CA DLP.</font></li>
</ul>
</li>      
</ul>
</li>




         </ul>




</li>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
div.container {

margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 10%;


}

div.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1em white;
    float: left;

}



nav {

/*background-image: url("http://teams.barclays.intranet/sites/compliancertb/Shared%20Documents/rtb3.bmp ");*/

background-color: #CCFFFF;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 40px;

}


.back div {
width: 930px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #DBFFFF;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 0 13px 0 13px;
font-family: Barclays Sans;
font-size: 13px;
}


tr.spaceUnder > td
{
padding-bottom: 1em;



}


.third-menu{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}


.dropdown-submenu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
}


#mn-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    height: 30px;


}
.mn-sidebar {
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
    background: #333333;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 2;
}


#mn-cont {
  display: block;
    vertical-align: top;     
    position: relative;
    padding: 10;
}
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
}
.cnt-mcont {
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 15px 30px 30px 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
    height: 101vh;
}
.mn-sidebar .mn-toggle {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mn-vnavigation {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #CCFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCFFFF;
border-left: 5px solid #CCFFFF;
border-right: 5px solid #CCFFFF;

}
.mn-vnavigation li a {
  border-top: 2px solid #CCFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 18px 13px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-submenu >
.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  /*height: 590px; */
  width: 310px;
  background: #333333;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > 
.dropdown-menu {

    display: list-item;
}


.dropdown-submenu > a:after {

    display: list-item;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.parent {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.bottom-mn {
    bottom:0px;         
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

js:

```
$('.child').hide(); //Hide children by default
$('.parent').children().click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```

Then codepen link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpxVdv

Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Did you try `left: -310px` on `dropdown-menu` class?

Comment: You want to open 1st and 2nd sub menu to left side of the main menu or the 2nd menu only?

Comment: I mean I want the above item to open on the right and the below item to open on the left.

Comment: @XahedKamal: So, for Large Holdings, I want all its submenus to open on right still, and for Orchestra, I want all its submenus to open on the left. I will position the whole dropdown in the center later.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu css` rule:

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: list-item;
    left: -310px;
}
```

Obviously you need a space on the left hand side to accommodate this:

```
.mn-sidebar {
  margin-left: 600px;
  ...
}
```

**EDIT** based on below OP comments:

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: list-item;
}
.dropdown-submenu:nth-child(2):hover > .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-submenu:nth-child(2) > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: list-item;
    left: -310px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it does it for both the items. Now, for both items it's displaying on the left, I want for Large Holdings, all its submenus to open on right still, and for Orchestra, all its submenus to open on the left

Comment: Then you need to leave `.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu` as it is, and only target `.dropdown-submenu:nth-child(2):hover > .dropdown-menu`. See my **Edit**

Comment: Please see my updated codepen.  Basically that is what I want. So, the dropdown on the right side, should display its submenus on the left. And its all messing up. :(

Comment: Oh. That's mess indeed ;) And completely different story now. So I think your requirement is to have two separated sidebars, each one of them containing a list of items, one floated to left and one floated to right. If this is the case - then you need to totally rebuild your markup, and start it from there. I initially thought you need [this](http://codepen.io/hedgehog34/pen/epeNvo?editors=110). Let me know where exactly you want to go with that.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out why my dropdown on the right side is not appearing properly on hover.

Comment: For that you need totally different html structure - build 2 lists, float them respectively, apply what you initially shown, to left one, then write another set of rules to one on the right

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks! Let me try. :)

Comment: Also, could you tell me one last thing? When I do that, and when I hover, say on the droopdown menu on the left, then its submenus come beneath the other drop down menu. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I'd need to see your code to answer that, but in your codepen, submenus appear on the the right hand side of dropdown item

Comment: Can you see the dropdown on the left in the codepen page? The conflicts and control room one? So when you hover over it. Doesn't its submenu go beneath the dropdown on the right?

Comment: Ah that one - you must have been looking on that on smaller screen than mine, but this seems to be a `z-index` issue - remove `z-index:2` from `.mn-sidebar` rule